# How to access the buttons that are child of custom list view?

Tags: android

I have 3 toggle buttons in a custom list view. How do I implement onclick listeners for these buttons. I cant do it in the adapter class as it does not have onCreate. And I am stuck as I dont know how I can access the child buttons of a listview.

```
mytoggle1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (!isChecked) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "This Level is Locked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {
                mytoggle1.setChecked(true);
                String str = (String) mytoggle1.getText();
                int curr_level = Integer.parseInt(str);
                SharedPreferences sharedpreference = getContext().getSharedPreferences(
                        getString(R.string.preference_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreference.edit();
                editor.putInt(getString(R.string.current_level), curr_level);
                editor.apply();
                Intent i = new Intent(this, GamePage.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        }
    });
```

This is my listener in the getView method. This is giving error that it is unable to resolve getString(), startActivity(), in the line Intent i = new Intent(this, GamePage.class) it gives error that it us unable to resolve constructor Intent.

Comment: Please post your code

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in getView of the adapter

```
 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null){
       LayoutInflater layoutInflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
       convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
    }

    Button button1 = (Button)   convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
    });    

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: I have tried that. I am trying to implement Intents and shared preferences in the onClick method but it gives error - unable to resolve startActivity() method of Intent and getString() method in shared pref

Answer (score 0):

You should go like this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview, parent, false);
    Button lvButton = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.lvButton);
    lvButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //...
        }
    });
}
```

And don't forget to define these on your xml to prevent listview not clickable

- ListView -> android:focusable="true"
- Button -> android:focusable="false"